# Chrome does not render frowning face emoji in color when using sans-serif font-face

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, emoji

On macOS, for some reason, the `sans-serif` font (which I think resolves to Helvetica) will always render certain emojis in monochrome form, even when the emoji character has the *emoji presentation sequence* (0xFE0F).

I often have `sans-serif` as the last fallback font in my styles, but this is causing problems in Chrome when rendering emojis because now some emojis will not render in color.

This only happens in Chrome; Firefox and Safari render the emojis correctly in color.

Is this a Chrome bug? How can I fallback to the default sans-serif font while preserving color emojis?

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>default:</td><td>foo ☹️</td></tr>
  <tr><td>serif:</td><td style="font-family: serif">foo ☹️</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sans-serif:</td><td style="font-family: sans-serif">foo ☹️</td></tr>
</table>
```

Chrome screenshot:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Firefox screenshot:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

---

- Chrome 97.0.4692.71
- macOS 12.1

---

**Edit**: This issue may be relevant: [Issue 964527: Chrome often ignores emoji and text variation selectors U+FE0F and U+FE0E](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=964527)

Comment: I am on chrome 97.0.4692.71, Windows 11, and it looks the same for me.

Comment: I think that's just how helvetica displays that character. Maybe you could use the "slightly frowning face" instead of the full frown `&#128577;`.

Comment: @sallf But Firefox and Safari render it correctly even when you specify Helvetica. Chrome is not resolving the font correctly for that character.

Comment: I’m also getting this (macOS 12.2.1 chrome 103.0.5060.134). It affects "smiling face" as well. My work-around is to use `<span class="emoji">&#x2639;&#xFE0F;</span>` and `span.emoji{font-family:serif}`. Thank you for figuring out that it's a font-dependent bug.